# A portable function to create a bmp file from raw bytes?

Tags: c++, unix, bitmap

I have an array of raw bytes and I want to make a bmp file from those bytes. That is, I have to fill bitmap header structre and other things, then write down the bytes so I have a bmp file in the proper format.

As I need this for some quick check only, I wonder if there is a portable method to do this - take raw bytes and save them as a bmp file. Any Windows version won't do as I'm writing that on Unix.

Alternatively, I can save those bytes as any other image format - I only need to have a quick look at the resulting picture.

Comment: TGA is also a pretty simple format to write a header for, in order to dump raw image data for viewing. I think I've probably written such a function dozens of times... What format is your data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will give you a [.ppm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm_format) image from a byte array. The `"P6"` specifies binary format 3 byte per pixel, but plain text is also supported and various forms of grayscale. The reason you should use this is that it is easy as can be and most *nix systems have a bunch of ppmto*-tools: ppmtobmp, ppmtojpeg, ..., ppmtopng... you name it.

```
typedef struct {
    int width;
    int height;
    uint8_t *data;
    size_t size;
} ppm_image;

size_t ppm_save(ppm_image *img, FILE *outfile) {
    size_t n = 0;
    n += fprintf(outfile, "P6\n# THIS IS A COMMENT\n%d %d\n%d\n", 
                 img->width, img->height, 0xFF);
    n += fwrite(img->data, 1, img->width * img->height * 3, outfile);
    return n;
}
```

There is also ppmtocad... who would have guessed?

Comment: Thanks a lot, it has worked out

Answer (score 5):

This is the code I use for .bmp Greyscale images

To save as color bitmap, just make sure about not using the palette (for 24bits)

```
void SaveBitmapToFile( BYTE* pBitmapBits, LONG lWidth, LONG lHeight,WORD wBitsPerPixel, LPCTSTR lpszFileName )
{
    RGBQUAD palette[256];
    for(int i = 0; i < 256; ++i)
    {
        palette[i].rgbBlue = (byte)i;
        palette[i].rgbGreen = (byte)i;
        palette[i].rgbRed = (byte)i;
    }

    BITMAPINFOHEADER bmpInfoHeader = {0};
    // Set the size
    bmpInfoHeader.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
    // Bit count
    bmpInfoHeader.biBitCount = wBitsPerPixel;
    // Use all colors
    bmpInfoHeader.biClrImportant = 0;
    // Use as many colors according to bits per pixel
    bmpInfoHeader.biClrUsed = 0;
    // Store as un Compressed
    bmpInfoHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;
    // Set the height in pixels
    bmpInfoHeader.biHeight = lHeight;
    // Width of the Image in pixels
    bmpInfoHeader.biWidth = lWidth;
    // Default number of planes
    bmpInfoHeader.biPlanes = 1;
    // Calculate the image size in bytes
    bmpInfoHeader.biSizeImage = lWidth* lHeight * (wBitsPerPixel/8);

    BITMAPFILEHEADER bfh = {0};
    // This value should be values of BM letters i.e 0x4D42
    // 0x4D = M 0×42 = B storing in reverse order to match with endian

    bfh.bfType = 'B'+('M' << 8);
    // <<8 used to shift ‘M’ to end

    // Offset to the RGBQUAD
    bfh.bfOffBits = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER) + sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER) + sizeof(RGBQUAD) * 256;
    // Total size of image including size of headers
    bfh.bfSize = bfh.bfOffBits + bmpInfoHeader.biSizeImage;
    // Create the file in disk to write
    HANDLE hFile = CreateFile( lpszFileName,GENERIC_WRITE, 0,NULL,
        CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,NULL);

    if( !hFile ) // return if error opening file
    {
        return;
    }

    DWORD dwWritten = 0;
    // Write the File header
    WriteFile( hFile, &bfh, sizeof(bfh), &dwWritten , NULL );
    // Write the bitmap info header
    WriteFile( hFile, &bmpInfoHeader, sizeof(bmpInfoHeader), &dwWritten, NULL );
    // Write the palette
    WriteFile( hFile, &palette[0], sizeof(RGBQUAD) * 256, &dwWritten, NULL );
    // Write the RGB Data
    if(lWidth%4 == 0)
    {
        WriteFile( hFile, pBitmapBits, bmpInfoHeader.biSizeImage, &dwWritten, NULL );
    }
    else
    {
        char* empty = new char[ 4 - lWidth % 4];
        for(int i = 0; i < lHeight; ++i)
        {
            WriteFile( hFile, &pBitmapBits[i * lWidth], lWidth, &dwWritten, NULL );
            WriteFile( hFile, empty,  4 - lWidth % 4, &dwWritten, NULL );
        }
    }
    // Close the file handle
    CloseHandle( hFile );
}
```

Comment: Perfect. Worked for me. Only change required is to bmpInfoHeader.biHeight = -lHeight; for Top-to-Bottom image.

Comment: What to do if I want to convert raw data into HBITMAP ?

Answer (score 2):

You could use [SOIL](http://lonesock.net/soil.html), it's lightweight, portable, and although aimed for OpenGL it can load images (and also save images) and give you back the raw data.

Here's some example usage usage (from the SOIL site)

```
   /* load an image as a heightmap, forcing greyscale (so channels should be 1) */
   int width, height, channels;
   unsigned char *ht_map = SOIL_load_image
   (
    "terrain.tga",
    &width, &height, &channels,
    SOIL_LOAD_L
   );
```

Here's the readable formats that SOIL has to offer:

```
Readable Image Formats:
BMP - non-1bpp, non-RLE (from stb_image documentation)
PNG - non-interlaced (from stb_image documentation)
JPG - JPEG baseline (from stb_image documentation)
TGA - greyscale or RGB or RGBA or indexed, uncompressed or RLE
DDS - DXT1/2/3/4/5, uncompressed, cubemaps (can't read 3D DDS files yet)
PSD - (from stb_image documentation)
HDR - converted to LDR, unless loaded with *HDR* functions (RGBE or RGBdivA or RGBdivA2)
```

EDIT: You can also use [stb_image](http://nothings.org/stb_image.c) (which is also cross-platform and portable) if you prefer, which has all documentation and such in the single file.

Answer (score 2):

Try [EasyBMP](http://easybmp.sourceforge.net/), it is open-source cross-platform C++ library and it is just fun to create BMP files with it:

```
BMP AnImage;
// Set size to 640 × 480
AnImage.SetSize(640,480);
// Set its color depth to 32-bits
AnImage.SetBitDepth(32);

// Set one of the pixels
AnImage(14,18)->Red = 255;
AnImage(14,18)->Green = 255;
AnImage(14,18)->Blue = 255;
AnImage(14,18)->Alpha = 0;

AnImage.WriteToFile("Output.bmp");
```

Answer (score 1):

[Boost GIL](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/gil/doc/index.html) supports read/write to JPG, TIFF and PNG.

Being heavily template-based you can adapt your image format to the library. It may be an overkill for you tho.

Answer (score -2):

Just take a look at the typedefs for `BITMAPFILEHEADER` and `BITMAPINFOHEADER` from WinGDI, the fields are easy.  Make sure you have 16-bit int for WORD and 32-bit int for DWORD.  If you're doing RGBRGBRGB... it's super-easy to fill in the headers and write out the data...